# How to keep my dog from rolling in dirt?

Tags: dogs, training, ears-nose-throat

I have an english bulldog and she loves finding dirt patches on my property and rolling around.

Not a big deal. I don't mind her getting dirty and having fun. The issue though is that it often leads to ear infections and that is what I want to prevent.

Has anyone ever dealt with this sort of thing? If so, any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you clean the dog afterwards?

Comment: I dust her off and pat her down every time. At least once a month, I give her a full bath.

Comment: I think that this question is best suited for a professional veterinarian. Not only he has the knowledge, but he also has access to the dog, to assess and address his particular condition. Please do not ask strangers on the internet about health issues, just consult a proper specialist. Just explain to the doctor everything you explained us here, so he can have the best understanding of the problem and the context.

Answer (score 1):

If your dog gets ear infections, the reason is probably not the rolling in the dirt. For that to lead to an infection, actual objects (like grass seeds) have to get stuck in her ear. That's very unlikely. And dogs have a habit of shaking their head after rolling in dirt, which flings dirt away fron the head.

If your dog gets ear infections regularily, the most likely reasons are the baths or an allergy.

Whenever you bathe your dog you should **never** pour water over her head or face. Any water that gets into the ears creates a warm and moist environment that bacteria and fungi love. Instead leave her head dry or if she's very dirty, wipe her head with a damp, but not dripping wash cloth.

Allergies have a tendency to manifest in the ears of dogs. I don't know how exactly that works, but many dogs with mild allergies get itchy ears as the first or the only symptom. You can ask your vet to do an allergy test, or you can switch to hypoallergenic dog foot for at least 4 weeks and see if it improves. You can read more information about food allergies and ear infections in [this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/37131/12501).